# Peterson's Algorithm - Preemptive or Non preemptive?

Tags: c, algorithm, process, preemptive

I am looking online for peterson's algorithm, and I cant seem to distinguish whether or not it is preemptive.

**Preemptive** - Non voluntary scheduling, and OS decides when to stop the process

**Non-preemptive** - Voluntarily giving up CPU once process is complete

[image]

I feel that peterson's algorithm seems to be non preemptive since there is no mention about priority of processes.

Is that correct? Would somebody be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: Where did you get these definitions? They look - incomplete - at best.

Comment: I found this on an online example - Just looking to see if my answer for the above code is correct?

Comment: "somewhere" is really a very good reference fo an important definition. You should continue to use such references (disclaimer: comment may include sarcasm). And an algorithm is in general neither. That is a matter of implementation. Please do more research with reliable references. You seem to confuse some phrases and concepts.

Comment: And: **Don't post images unless required for the question!**

Comment: Off topic: Peterson's algorithm was developed in 1981 when processors were still quite primitive, i.e. simple. You should not attempt to use Peterson's algorithm on modern processors. See [lockless multithreading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418650(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: By any chance is this a coursework question you had last year? Because if so, same! Just a year out.

Answer (score 1):

Peterson's Algorithm is neither **preemptive** or **non-preemptive**.

[Preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) is a notion of the underlying Operating System, more precisely the **scheduler**. The task of the scheduler is to assign timeslots to processes in a timely (*pun intended*) manner.

The scheduler can interrupt a process regarding of wait-state.

However, it's "prudent" to signal the scheduler that *now is a good time to let another process run* by utilizing wait-states.

For Peterson's Algorithm this signal should be inside the `while`-loop. A simple `sleep` should suffice.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) also mentions:

> The while condition works even with preemption

So to conclude as we began:
Peterson's Algorithm is neither **preemptive** or **non-preemptive**.

Answer (score 0):

Peterson's solution works for a preemptive process. It might fail for a non-preemptive process.

Suppose both process wish to enter the critical section.

```
do {
   flag[0] = 1; 
   turn = 1;
   while(flag[1] && turn == 1);
   CS
   flag[0] = 0;
   RS
   } while(1);

do {
   flag[1] = 1; 
   turn = 0;
   while(flag[0] && turn == 0);
   CS
   flag[1] = 0;
   RS
   } while(1);
```

If turn = 1 process 0 will be in a spinlock. It is wasting CPU cycles. It is preempted so that the other process (i.e. process 1) gets chance.